# Bitmaps and memory resources

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I am writing an app that makes use of bitmap images generated by the camera. These are cropped and stored by the app. The user can use these images as player tokens in the next activity. A problem exists where the application appears to be holding onto all these images and storing them in memory until the app crashes.

To recap: an activity (selection screen) holds up to 19 images.  The next activity (game screen) holds between 1 and 8 images, selected from the selection screen. This works fine (although the app is hitting roughly 120mb by this stage).

When a user goes back to the selection screen to start a new game, and selects images again, we are hitting in excess of 170mb and the app crashes.

I have been reading up on this and trying different solutions offered by people and nothing so far has made any difference.   Is there something simple I am missing?   Or is this going to require a complex rewiring of everything I have done so far?

### Edit

Images added using the code below. In player selection screen:

```
File file = getFileStreamPath("imgPlayer1.png");
    if(file.exists()) {
        btnP1.setImageBitmap(getThumbnail("imgPlayer1.png"));
        g.setPlayer1img(true);
    } else {
        btnP1.setImageResource(R.drawable.player_blank);
        g.setPlayer1img(false);
    }
```

On gameplay screen:

```
if (g.getPlayer1Chosen()) {
        btnGP1.setImageBitmap(getThumbnail("imgPlayer1.png"));
        btnGP1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Original creation code:

```
try {
        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("img" + foo + ".png",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("saveToInternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
```

I had read about condensing the size of the image when you call it, but the responses were that image quality is substantially diminished.  This cannot happen. Also, it seems if I did only that, the problem would still exist, it would merely leak memory at a slower rate.

Comment: did u compress it when user selects it ?

Comment: @Quick Learner:  Thank you for your response. Code used added above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no solution to this.  Image usage on Android is very inefficient. With the encouragement towards material design now evident, we converted the whole appearance of the app. It now uses far less images and more colourful squares (Views).  Memory issues resolved.